# php cli custom ini not loading

Tags: php, command-line-interface, php-ini

A script is called from command line using :

```
/fullpath/php -q -c /fullpath/php.ini /fullpath/script.php
```

I want it to use the normal php.ini and not the one for cli, but the -c flag is not working.

What could cause this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check which configuration files are actually loaded with the `--ini` switch.

Here's what my normal configuration looks like:

```
krakjoe@fiji:/usr/src/php-src$ php --ini
```

Yields:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php-cli.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/apcu.ini,
/etc/php.d/auto.ini,
/etc/php.d/autostrict.ini,
/etc/php.d/ds.ini,
/etc/php.d/inspector.ini,
/etc/php.d/memcached.ini,
/etc/php.d/mongodb.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/opcache.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/uopz.ini,
/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini,
/etc/php.d/yaml.ini
```

Note that, it loads `php-cli.ini`, because it exists and we are in `cli`.

If we do this:

```
krakjoe@fiji:/usr/src/php-src$ php -c php.ini-development --ini
```

We get:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/src/php-src/php.ini-development
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/apcu.ini,
/etc/php.d/auto.ini,
/etc/php.d/autostrict.ini,
/etc/php.d/ds.ini,
/etc/php.d/inspector.ini,
/etc/php.d/memcached.ini,
/etc/php.d/mongodb.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/opcache.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/uopz.ini,
/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini,
/etc/php.d/yaml.ini
```

This time `php-cli.ini` was not loaded, the specified one was, but so were all the files in scan dir too.

Finally, if we do this:

```
krakjoe@fiji:/usr/src/php-src$ php -c php.ini-development -n --ini
```

We get:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/src/php-src/php.ini-development
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

So, adding the additional switch `-n`, stops PHP from using the scan directory configuration.