# How to force PHP CLI to read my .user.ini file?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, ini

In the [documentation for `php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php), it says that "`php.ini` is searched for in... [the] current working directory **(except CLI)**".

Why does it not read my [`.user.ini` file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) when running via CLI? Is there any way to configure PHP so that it always checks the current directory (or the directory of the script) for extra ini files?

I'm on OSX, running Homebrew PHP. My workaround is to run PHP like this, which does work (it picks up all of the regular ini files and also the one in the current working directory), but it's super awkward:

```
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR="/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d:." php [options]
```

Is there any way to configure php so that this is the default behavior? Am I missing something?

Comment: You could set the environment variable in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Using `.` in the directory list is dangerous. It means that the behavior of the script will depend on the user's current directory when they run it.

Comment: You can ceck the loaded ini files using `php --ini`, you could set up the ini file to load additional ini files in "X" folder or check if it is doing already (it's common that additional ini files are loaded for php libraries like `pdo` or similar)

Comment: @Barmar Dangerous or not, that's exactly what I want: "the behavior of the script will depend on the user's current directory" - yes please. Tell me how to do that.

Comment: And thanks @Barmar; yeah - adding to `.bashrc` is exactly what I'll do if there's no better option.

Comment: I think that's the only option. Most defaults for PHP are set in `php.ini`, but obviously you can't use that to set the default for finding the file in the first place.

Comment: Consider using `php -c /path/to/custom/php.ini` or `php -c /path/to/custom/php.ini -n` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35228845/82216).

Answer (score 6):

Set the `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` variable in your `.bashrc`:

```
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d:.
```

Then open a new Terminal window and it should use this setting.